# What is the preferred conventional way of incorporating a third party library in Python open source projects?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm working on a new Python authentication library for WSGI frameworks and want to use the [python-openid](https://github.com/openid/python-openid) and maybe some other third-party libs too. I see 2 options:

- Distribute my library with a copy of the **third-party library** inside (via GIT submodules)
- Let the user of **my library** resolve the dependency on the **third-party library** by himself

The question is:

**What is the preferred conventional way of incorporating a third party library in Python open source projects?**

Comment: Why not using install_requires in your setup.py????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preffered way is to use [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)/[distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) and define a [setup.py](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) for your project that downloads third-party libraries via [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org).

Here's an extract from one of my projects. Note the use of setup/install/test/extras-require keyword arguments, which is what you're looking for

```
import distribute_setup
distribute_setup.use_setuptools()

import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Utility function to read the README file.
# Used for the long_description.  It's nice, because now 1) we have a top level
# README file and 2) it's easier to type in the README file than to put a raw
# string in below ...

def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
    name='buildboticon',
    version='0.3.2',
    author='Marcus Lindblom',
    author_email='macke@yar.nu',
    description=('A buildbot monitoring utility'),
    license='GPL 3.0',
    keywords='buildbot systemtray pyqt',

    url='http://bitbucket.org/marcusl/buildboticon',
    download_url='http://packages.python.org/buildboticon',

    package_dir={'':'src'},
    packages=find_packages('src', exclude=['*.tests']),
    long_description=read('README'),

    entry_points={
        'setuptools.installation': [
            'eggsecutable = bbicon:main',
        ],
        'gui_scripts': [
            'buildboticon = bbicon:main',
        ]
    },

    setup_requires=[
        'setuptools_hg',
    ],

    tests_require=[
        'unittest2 >= 0.5',
        'mock >= 0.7.0b4',
    ],

    install_requires=[
        'pyyaml >= 0.3',
#        'pyqt >= 4.7'   # PyQt doesn't have anything useful on PyPi :(
    ],

    extras_require={
        'speech':  ['pyspeech >= 1.0'],
#        'phidgets': ['PhidgetsPython >= 2.1.7'],
    },
```

Full file here: https://bitbucket.org/marcusl/buildboticon/src/5232de5ead73/python/setup.py

Comment: Third party dependencies are configured using the install_requires parameter

Comment: @CRUSADER: Yeah. I added an example. Hard to find good doc for it though.

Comment: When I tried to `import setuptools` in Python 2.7.2 on OS X (on what I assume is a clean install), it worked without a hitch... does Apple bundle setuptools with Python?